# Modifying WordPress Comment Template

Tags: php, wordpress

so I just installed a super plugin that manages WordPress user registrations, profiles, etc. to be displayed on the front-end. It also integrates a link to the user's profile in the comment section.

All I have to do is replace the original WP code for the comments

```
<?php printf( '%s ', sprintf( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite>', get_comment_author_link() ) ); ?>
```

to be replaced with this

```
<?php 
if ($comment->user_id) { 
printf('%s', '<a href="'.$userpro->permalink( $comment->user_id).'">'.userpro_profile_data('display_name', $comment->user_id) . '</a>'); 
?>
} 
else { 
printf('%s', get_comment_author_link()); 
} 
?>
```

But whenever I replace the custom code with the original one, I get an error message. Does anyone know as to why this happens?

The error message says something along the lines of "unexpected end $" or something.

But looking at the custom code, I cannot see where the problem lies.

Does anyone know what could the problem be?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your code to this:

```
<?php 
    if ($comment->user_id) { 
        printf('%s', '<a href="'.$userpro->permalink( $comment->user_id).'">'.userpro_profile_data('display_name', $comment->user_id) . '</a>'); 
    } else { 
        printf('%s', get_comment_author_link()); 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Wow! It worked! Thanks a lot! Could you please tell me what was wrong with the initial code, and why it gave out an error message?

Comment: You had an extra closing tag `?>` before the else

Comment: Oh, don't know how I could have overlooked that. But thanks anyways :)